# Navigating through nested parent frames in IE 10 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

I'm trying to access an element within the DOM that's in a different frame than the one I'm currently in. I'm trying to go to the parent frame and then access another frame, two levels below (**Note** **these tags are** `< frame >` **NOT** `< iframe >`). I was able to accomplish this in Chrome but I am unable to do so in IE 10. I have the following:

```
var divElem = parent.frames['frameOne'].contentWindow.frameTwo.document.getElementById('myDiv');
```

I tried `contentDocument` as well as `contentWindow` in IE, but it returns as undefined. How can I correctly do this in IE 10?

Comment: Did you try: parent.frames['frameOne'].document ? And is frameTwo an iframe in frameOne?

Comment: Actual both frameOne and frameTwo are frame, not iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer was much easier than anticipated while using `< frame >`. The following worked for me in IE 10.

```
var divElem =  parent.frames[2][1].document.getElementById('myDiv');
```

Answer (score 1):

Get frame's document with cross-browser conditional fallback, like so:

```
//get frame by ID (assign ID to your frame, easier that way)
var frm = document.getElementById("frameOne");

//get frame's document (cross-browser fallback)
var doc = frm.contentDocument? frm.contentDocument: frm.contentWindow.document;

//assign some HTML to frame - in your case you're probably loading content via src
doc.body.innerHTML = '<div id="myDiv">Test</div>'

//access elements within frame
console.log(doc.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML)
```

**Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pp6w54sv/**

Comment: This is what I originally tried upon doing my research but, it seems to work with frame and note iframe